# DevOps: Building a production server

Tags: python, git, digital-ocean

I'm completely new to devops and I'm quickly becoming overwhelmed with all the options.

I write python web applications as a solo developer, on my local machine. I have a "staging" server on DigitalOcean, I have multiple websites under different subdomains (eg. myapp.staging.mywebsite.dev). I use git on my local machine and use branches to create multiple versions of my apps and then I use git to push my code to this server so I can see how it looks on the web.

When I'm happy with my web app I want to be able to deploy it to a separate production server on DigitalOcean so I can get real users using my apps. I could just use git to push my code to a new server but are there any other options that will help me create a live site?

Comment: "Best practice" questions are generally off-topic here, likewise questions that aren't narrowly focused on a specific problem with existing code. This might be a better fit for [programmers.se]

Comment: (I say that as someone who's been responsible for CI/CD in more than one shop; it's an interesting topic, but too much room for opinions and design choices to be on topic here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy do you know if it would be possible to just transfer this question over to software engineering dot SE?

Comment: @joanis It's possible, but requires a moderator's assistance -- back when it could be done automatically via a close reason there were too many SE sites getting questions transferred when they didn't agree that those questions complied with their rules.

Answer (score 0):

In our systems, we handle this scenario with a dedicated `publish` branch.

The GitHub action workflow for publishing starts like this:

```
name: Publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [publish]
```

so it's only triggered by a push to `publish` and it deploys to the `gh-pages` branch in our case.

All the draft work and the review versions live in different branches, with the `publish` branch itself set to be protected so nothing can pushed to it without proper review.

We also have a `review` branch where we stage things for pre-publication review, and we merge into `publish` from `review`. A colleague has set that part up, but the review branch gets deployed into a staging subdomain similar to yours so we can review it before publication.